# JavaScript canvas ctx.getImageData running out of memory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I made a program in JavaScript that draws a cycloid. It works fine but if it runs for a few minutes it sometimes gets an error and the whole thing stops working.

`render()` function is called on every tick with different shapes to draw.

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var imgData;

function render(){
   ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0); //similar to ctx.clearRect()

   //draw a part of a line (I want to show this part of the line and all previous)

   imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

   //darw a pencil (it is moving and I don't want it to leave trail)
}
```

This is an error I'm getting:

`Uncaught RangeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Out of memory at ImageData creation`

I get this error **only in Google Chrome** the code works good in other browsers (even IE).

Why does the problem occur and how can I fix the program so it doesn't generate this error anymore?

Comment: What is the size of the image ?

Comment: The canvas is as big as the browser window (around 1900x1200)

Comment: I am asking about the weight ?[MB ?]

Comment: Are you using `setInterval` to tick the animation, and what is the interval. Use `requestAnimationFrame` rather than setInterval. Also why are you using imageData it is so very slow and about the worst way to render anything.

Comment: I don't know. `imgData.data` is Uint8ClampedArray[4020400]

Comment: @Rayon 1900*1200*4 = 9Mb

Comment: @Blindman67 I am already using `requestAnimationFrame` and for rendering I am using `ctx.lineTo`, `ctx.stroke`, `ctx.fillRect` ... I use `ctx.getImageData` just to save the image before I draw pencil on it.

Comment: Create a second offscreen canvas the same size as the imagedata you are saving. Draw the background onto it, then use it to clear the canvas. Chrome (and I am surprised FF not spitting it) dont handle them memory management of imageData very well. GC does not get the time to clean up

Comment: @Blindman67 in FF it works OK. If I create 2 canvases I still have to use getImageData to copy background from one canvas to another.

Comment: No canvas is an image use `offScreenContext.drawImage(canvas,0,0)`. You can draw a canvas just like any image, in fact on Chrome drawing a canvas is quicker than drawing an image.

Comment: @Blindman67 I tried it and it doesnt work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRLdBR?editors=1010 I used this tutorial http://devbutze.blogspot.si/2014/02/html5-canvas-offscreen-rendering.html

Comment: Spelling you are setting the off screen canvas to the wrong size. Check spelling of height, not hieght

Comment: @Blindman67 thank you, now it works. I'll try to use it in my program.